# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^n}{1+x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I try to use First mean value theorem for definite integrals like this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^n}{1+x}}dx} = \lim_{n \to \infty} c^n \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{1+x}}dx = \ln{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}{c^n}$$

where $0 \leq c \leq 1$,

but then if $c = 1$, the result is $\ln{2}$; else it yields $0$.

What should I do next?

Comment: We can try $$I_m=\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_0^1\dfrac{x^m\ dx}{1+x},I_n+I_{n+1}=?$$

Comment: The constant $c$ also depends on $n$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $$I_n + I_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{1}x^mdx$$ wow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea almost works, the problem is that $c$ must not be equal to $1$. There is an remedy for that.

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^n}{1+x}}dx} &= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \left (\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{x^n}{1+x}}dx+\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}{\frac{x^n}{1+x}}dx\right)\\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( (1-\epsilon)^n\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}{\frac{1}{1+x}}dx+\epsilon\right )\\
&\leq \epsilon
\end{align}
Since the previous holds for every $\epsilon>0$, we get 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^n}{1+x}}dx}=0$$

Comment: How do you get second equal? I think you should use another variable instead of $\epsilon$ outside the integral.

Comment: $\frac{x^n}{1+x}\leq 1$ and $1-(1-\epsilon)=\epsilon$. Also $x\leq (1-\epsilon)$, I didn't use the Mean Value theorem to make the proof easier to write, however I may as well have used it

Answer (score 6):

Another way: Use the inequality (for $0\leq x\leq 1$)
$$
0\leq \frac{x^n}{1+x}\leq x^n
$$
Integrate, and squeeze.